# Is there a list of points unique to Layamon's telling of the King Arthur story?

Tags: arthurian-legend, layamon

Is there a list of points unique to Layamon's retelling of the Arthurian legends? For example, as far as I can tell, the story of Arthur being raised in Avalon (as opposed to with Sir Ector) is unique to Layamon. Is there a list of these, or a paper that discusses these?